# Confluence: how to create multiple pages tree from text file (markdown) via script?

Tags: confluence

I tried web search `site:stackoverflow.com confluence create multiple pages tree from text file (markdown)` but did not find the answer to below:

*How to create multiple pages tree from text file (markdown)?*

I could not find standard macro in confluence for the task too. As I understand Confluence support scripting so it should be possible in automated way. I need tree of pages created in `Confluence` from indent formatted file (e.g. markdown) like below:

1. List item
2. List item

   1. List item

Answer (score 2):

In Confluence, page tree contains different pages which they can be parent and child.

You can create a Parent Page via REST API. According to Atlassian [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-rest-api-examples/) you can use following end point:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"type":"page","title":"new page",
"space":{"key":"TST"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is <br/> a new page</p>","representation":
"storage"}}}' http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/ | python -mjson.tool
```

In same documentation, it shows how you can create child page:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"type":"page","title":"new page",
"ancestors":[{"id":456}], "space":{"key":"TST"},"body":{"storage":{"value":
"<p>This is a new page</p>","representation":"storage"}}}'
http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/ | python -mjson.tool
```

Thus, you can create different pages via REST api and decide which one need to be parent and which one should be a child page. You just have to feed the endpoint with the content of your text file with the preferred language.